# Display a files icon in a PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, icons

I know there is a lot of these noob questions already.
I wrote a small code for display the `Icon` from a file in a `PictureBox` and its not working :|

```
Button6.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromHicon(
    New Icon(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, New Size(48, 48)).Handle
)
```

The error says:

> Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon

If anyone know whats the problem, please write it down.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Image` property of the `Button6` control? Also are you sure you are using a picturebox and not a button?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the file you are trying to open is not an `icon`. An `icon` file has extension **.ico**. Also you need to open the `OpenFileDialog1` before geting the selected file name:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        Button1.BackgroundImage = Bitmap.FromHicon(New Icon(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, New Size(48, 48)).Handle)

End If
```